# String concatenation by passing a parameter

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

This is what I have:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
    }
    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("myserverip");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        cout << "Could not connect";
        // system("pause");
    }
    cout << "Connected.\n";
    send(Socket,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myserverip\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myserverip\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);
    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){        
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
```

(This code is inside a loop). I would like to set my server-host in the header I'll send by using a variable. That's actually what I tried to do:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
}
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname(myhost);
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) {
    return 1;
}
send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + myhost + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + myhost + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0) {
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
        cout << buffer[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
```

This code also is inside a loop. The global variable is declared like this:

```
string myhost;
```

But I can't get it to work, especially on this line:

```
send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + myhost + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + myhost + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
```

How can I fix this? I am a beginner on C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable of type `std::string` and then use `std::string::c_str()` to get the C string from it that you can use in the call to `send`.

```
std::string str = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
str += myhost;
str += "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

send(Socket, str.c_str(), str.size(), 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is `strlen()` the equivalent in this case to `str.size()`?

Comment: That is correct. You can also use `std::string::length()`. They are equivalent.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the point. My real question is why not to declare the variable which contains the http-request-header as a global variable. In the OP I said I use that code in a loop. So in this method, I will declare pointlessly many times that variable, right?

Comment: That is the preferred method. Don't declare a variable in any higher scope than you need to.

Comment: can you correct me if I am wrong? By my experiences, I know that declaring a variable in a loop is a bad practice (I declare it each time in the loop).

Comment: note that `strlen()` can't be applied to a `string` variable, only to a C string (like a string literal).

Comment: @programmerjake yes, but that was actually implied. I must ofcourse use `str.size()` for an `std::string`, but for an array of chars (for a C-string) I must use `strlen()`. But obviously it should depend from which method I use.

Comment: In C++ declaring a variable has no runtime cost, what has a cost is constructing and destructing non-trivial objects. For instance, putting `int variable;` in a loop has no more cost than putting it at the beginning of the function, but a `string` variable has a cost associated with allocating and deallocating the memory to hold it's value.

Comment: The reason for not declaring a variable with a larger scope is to avoid bugs where you change the variable unintentionally and to associate the variables with the code that uses them.

Comment: @programmerjake I don't know which bug you are referring to. However, I still prefer to be safer by declaring the variable globally. Is it so bad?

Comment: I was not referring to a specific bug, but to avoiding creating bugs where you accidentally use the wrong variable name. If the variable is not in scope, then the compiler will tell you, otherwise you may not find the bug till much later.

Comment: If you want a global variable then you could use `static string str; str = ...` or `static thread_local string str; ...`. Both of these avoid constructing and destructing `str` every iteration but the variable's scope is still limited. When using static it runs the declaration only once, so each time through you need to reinitialize it in a separate statement.

Comment: @programmerjake please, could you explain constructing/destructing? So, if I declare it as a static string, am I advantaged? Also what about using const?

Comment: constructing and destructing are where the compiler inserts special function calls that setup and teardown `string`'s internals. I won't be available, so someone else please explain.